# What is the best analytics tool for an Android application?

Tags: android, google-analytics, flurry

I saw Flurry and Google-Analytics are good choices, what tool is more powerful and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using google analytics for android has too many advantages. In case you have a service which is available on internet ,android and iPhone, you can see the consolidated data of all these on a single page. Also, the API is very simple and use of custom variables can be done to track the events in the application. Check out their official page at 
http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

Answer (score 7):

I have used [UXCam](http://uxcam.com) which become very useful for me.  It has all the feature that should be in mobile analytical and UX optimization tools.
It has many features such as:

- Screen video recording
- User interaction data such as heatmap, timeline
- Camera video recording
- Feedback and bug reporting

Integration steps are also very easy and short. You have to add some permissions and services in manifest and add

```
 UXCam.startApplication(this);
```

on starting activity of your app. Docs are available [here](http://uxcam.com/docs).

Answer (score 5):

It depends whatever you want from an analytic. Check this page and maybe you can decide which one is the best for you. [Flurry-vs-Mixpanel-vs-Google-Mobile-Analytics-who-wins-Why](http://www.quora.com/Flurry-vs-Mixpanel-vs-Google-Mobile-Analytics-who-wins-Why)

Answer (score 3):

I am currently trying Countly http://count.ly/ and it looks very promising.
If you are not looking for experimentation you can try Google Analytics and Flurry which are more tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://try.crashlytics.com/ and really its amazing..

just Checkout listed trusted partner who integrated the same..